# is_home() or is_front_page() check with pagination does not show content of next page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have an index.php page where I have added the following code to display different content based on the page loaded:

```
if( is_page( 'my-account' ) ) {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/my-account', 'account' );
} else if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/album-grid', 'index' );
} else if( is_page( 'create-album')  ) {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/create-album', 'create-album' );
}
```

In album-grid.php I am using a WP_Query and a pagination. The pagination displays OK. When I click on **Next** link, it takes me to  `http://albumlocal.com/page/2` but does not does not show up anything. I am expecting to see the next set of records here.

Here is my code on `album-grid.php` file:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'taxonomy'          => 'album-category',
        'post_type'         => array('albums'),
        'posts_per_page'    => 10,
        'paged'             => $paged,
    )
);

if( $posts->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div class="grid-table" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
            <?php
            while ( $posts->have_posts() ) :$posts->the_post(); ?>
                <a class="grid-anchor" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <div class="grid-col">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <div class="grid-thumbnail">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('home_grid_thumbnail'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-action">
                            <i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Photos
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            <?php
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php echo paginate_links( array(
    'total' => $posts->max_num_pages,
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'format' => 'page/%#%'
)); ?>
```

I think when I am on second or any sub page (e.g. `http://albumlocal.com/page/2`) `is_home()` or `is_front_page()` is no longer been satisfied and hence it is not loading the required template part `album-grid.php` any more.

```
if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/album-grid', 'index' );
}
```

I am not sure if this the case, but if so, I don't know how to make it to work.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do ? There is a pagination on your homepage ?

Comment: No, the pagination is inside the template part `album-grid.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create in your theme folder :

- home.php for the Grid
- page template `page.create-album.php` with inside

---

```
<?php //Template Name: Create Album
//Here all the html and php
```

---

- page template `page.my-account.php` with inside

---

```
<?php //Template Name: My Account
//Here all the html and php
```

---

Everything will me automatically done, and you will no longer need :

```
if( is_page( 'my-account' ) ) {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/my-account', 'account' );
} else if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/album-grid', 'index' );
} else if( is_page( 'create-album')  ) {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/create-album', 'create-album' );
}
```

I dont' know  if it will fix the problem for you but, it will be cleaner i think, and i already have done pagination on the home.php this way without any problems.

**Just try, and if it's not working we will find another way :)**